# Questions about rails3 routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm upgrading my app to rails 3, and I am a bit confused about some of the routes. The resourceful ones are easy enough, but how can I set a generic rule for all actions in a specific controller. I tried something like this:

```
get 'custom/:action/' => {:controller => :custom}
```

But that didn't work. It seems the new format is "controller#action", but how can I specify the action to be variable?

Also, other than using named routes or resources, is it possible to do shorthand notation to name routes in a specific controller?

i.e. rather than:

```
get '/tasks', :controller => :home, :action => :tasks, :as => 'tasks_home'
get '/accounts', :controller => :home, :action => :accounts, :as => 'accounts_home'
```

is it possible to do something a little cleaner, like:

```
controller => :home do
  get :tasks
  get :accounts
end
```

And that would automatically created the named routes?

Comment: If it's a resource, then you can do 
`resources :posts do
  member do
    get 'dummy', :as => 'dummy_home'
    get 'dummy1', :as => 'dummy1_home'
  end
end
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use action as a variable like this:

```
resource :custom do
   match ':action'
end
```

This will generate

```
                   /custom/:action(.:format) customs#:action
     custom POST   /custom(.:format)         customs#create
 new_custom GET    /custom/new(.:format)     customs#new
edit_custom GET    /custom/edit(.:format)    customs#edit
            GET    /custom(.:format)         customs#show
            PUT    /custom(.:format)         customs#update
            DELETE /custom(.:format)         customs#destroy
```

So it will handle your action as a variable URL-s and will add some default CRUD actions as well.

Note that the controller name here is in plural. If you would like to use a route for a controller which name is in singular, use `resources` instead of `resource`.

The answer to the second question is almost identical to the first one, use resource:

```
resource :home do
    get :tasks
    get :accounts
end
```

generates:

```
   tasks_home GET    /home/tasks(.:format)     homes#tasks
accounts_home GET    /home/accounts(.:format)  homes#accounts
         home POST   /home(.:format)           homes#create
     new_home GET    /home/new(.:format)       homes#new
    edit_home GET    /home/edit(.:format)      homes#edit
              GET    /home(.:format)           homes#show
              PUT    /home(.:format)           homes#update
              DELETE /home(.:format)           homes#destroy
```

Note that the matched controller names are in plural again, because of the convention.

Comment: Thanks...this is actually how I was doing it in rails2, but it feels like a hack, since I am not using any of the resourceful routes. Essentially, I was adding something like this to disable those restful routes which don't have endpoints in these controllers: 

    resource :home, :except => [:new, :create, :edit, :destroy] do ... end

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is related to the persisted field being set to false on nested ActiveResource objects: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3107